# Spoofing the call stack inside a worker thread that processes queued tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, callstack

Let's say I have a worker thread with an input `Queue<Task>` which are processed inside a continuous `while` loop. Whenever outside code deposits a new `Task` into the queue, the worker awakes and awaits the task instance. If an exception is raised, however, I want to log the details, including the complete call stack, so I can determine which code path to blame.

Unfortunately, the call stack of the exception is rooted inside the worker thread. Which is understandable - it is the root-most code that executes the task.

The question is: could I hypothetically merge the exception's call stack with the call stack that deposited the task into worker thread's queue in the first place?

I know I can do it manually, by simply making note of the depositing call stack via `Environment.StackTrace` and logging it along with exception inside the worker. But that's still two separate stacks that I have to keep track of.

Is there a more clever way to spoof the exception's own call stack to look as if it was continuous? Because it sort of is - there's just a slight delay between the points when task is enqueued and dequeued.

**EDIT**: I'm basically looking for a way to do what C#'s `async` does with call stacks (i.e. merge them over all the thread hops that happen), only inside a regular thread under my control.

Comment: Could [`ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) be the answer? "*The exception is thrown as if it had flowed from the point where it was captured to the point where the Throw method is called.*"

Comment: @spender: I don't think so. That class is useful when an exception has to be rethrown while preserving its original stack. I'm already using it in other places, but it doesn't help me here. When the exception is thrown, its call stack is rooted at the worker thread's entry-point. The depositor's stack is long gone by that time, so there's no way to capture it inside try..catch.

Comment: @spender: Just to clarify: I tend to ask a bit difficult questions on SO and SE, for which I receive negative feedback more often than not. I upvoted your comment simply to acknowledge your positive attempt to help me. So thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I can do it manually, by simply making note of the depositing call stack

This is probably the cleaner solution.

> Is there a more clever way to spoof the exception's own call stack to look as if it was continuous?

Yes, there's a "clever" solution - and like most "clever" solutions, YMMV.

First, a quick note on terminology: [what you want isn't a call stack (where the code is returning to); its a causality chain (how the code got here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj891052.aspx).

You can use `AsyncLocal<T>` / `LogicalCallContext` to keep track of the causality chain yourself. One easily-overlooked gotcha is that [the data stored in the logical call context must be immutable](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html). A more serious (and thankfully more rare) problem with this approach is if you have infinitely "recursive" asynchronous calls, which normally work fine, but if you grow the causality chain on each invocation, you'll end up with unbounded memory usage.

Once you have this set up, you can use Fody / PostSharp / etc. to automatically inject the causality chain tracking into your methods.

I have an [AsyncDiagnostics library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncDiagnostics) that uses `LogicalCallContext` with `PostSharp` to auto-magically determine your causality chains. I'd try that first.